# Is it possible to get a callback on a parent function from an inner promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, timeout, promise

### [**Play with my JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S4m9A/58/)

Is it possible to use `$timeout` promise to make `scrollTo` chainable like I've shown below? If not, how can I write scrollTo, as a promise, so that I may callback using then?

**html:**

```
<div ng-click=toTop()>click me</div>
```

**js:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.toTop = function() {
        var bodyEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#body'));
        scrollTo_(bodyEl[0], 0, 500);

    };


    function scrollTo_(element, to, duration) {
        if (duration <= 0) {
                        $timeout.cancel(forward);
            console.log('yoyo');
            return forward;
        }
        var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
        var perTick = difference / duration * 10;
        var forward = $timeout(function() {
            element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
            scrollTo_(element, to, duration - 10);
        }, 10, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML, CSS as well. Please create jsFiddle

Comment: Updated. Anything else that I can do to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I would done the recursive promise:

```
function scrollTo_(element, to, duration) {
    if(duration<=0) return Promise.resolve();
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop,
        perTick = difference / duration * 10;
    return $timeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    }, 10, false).then(function(){
      duration -= 10;
      return scrollTo_(element, to, duration)
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to stop the timeout inbetween, I guess you could do something like:

```
var scrollTopTimeoutFlag = true, scrollTopTimeout;
function scrollTo_(element, to, duration) {
    if(duration<=0 || !scrollTopTimeoutFlag){
      if(scrollTopTimeout)  return $timeout.cancel(scrollTopTimeout);
      return $q.when();   // $q.when == Promise.resolve
    } 
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop,
        perTick = difference / duration * 10;
    scrollTopTimeout = $timeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    }, 10, false);
    return scrollTopTimeout.then(function(){
      duration -= 10;
      return scrollTo_(element, to, duration)
    });
}
```

Comment: Marked as correct but can you think of a method to still $timeout.cancel(timeout) the promise?

Comment: Moreover is there a way to do this using $q and not Promise.resolve?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to interpret "use $timeout promise to make `scrollTo` chainable like I've shown below", since `scrollTo` isn't chainable.  So let's assume `scrollTo` is to be made "thenable", by having it return a $q promise.

With that assumption in place, it seems reasonable that the returned promise should be resolved on completion of the scroll, or rejected if the scroll is stopped before completion (by another `scrollTo_()` call).

Here goes :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q) {
    var stopSignal = false;
    $scope.toTop = function() {
        var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#body'))[0];
        stopSignal = true; // stop previous.
        scrollTo_(0, 500).then(function() { // Yay, scrollTo_() is thenable!
            console.log('scroll complete');
        }, function() {
            console.log('scroll stopped');
        });
        function scrollTo_(to, duration) {
            var startTime = null,
                startPos = element.scrollTop,
                dfrd = $q.defer();
            function step(timestamp) {
                if(stopSignal) {
                    // This block kills an animation that's in progress.
                    // It doesn't affect freshly initiated animations.
                    stopSignal = false; // reset the `stopSignal` flag.
                    dfrd.reject(); // reject the deferred, to indicate non-completion
                    return; // prevent further animation by returning early and killing the recursion.
                }
                if (!startTime) {
                    stopSignal = false;
                    startTime = timestamp;
                }
                var progress = timestamp - startTime;
                if (progress < duration) {
                    element.scrollTop = startPos + (to - startPos) * progress / duration; // linear movement w.r.t. time, though not necessarily at regular intervals.
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(step); // recurse
                } else {
                    element.scrollTop = to; // ensure final position is accurate
                    dfrd.resolve();
                }
            }
            // This is horribly messy but necessary(?) for the stop signal to take effect.
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                stopSignal = false;
                window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            });
            return dfrd.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S4m9A/59/)** *Double-click to see a scroll effect stopped before another starts.*

As you can see, the 10ms timout-induced interval is avoided by dropping $timeout and :

- exploiting [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which is the modern way to orchestrate animations (though browser compatibility is currently an issue, esp IE < 10) guaranteeing that each user gets the best possible update rate that his/her browser can manage under prevailing processor load.
- working at each step, from an established base-time, giving better guaranteed linearity of movement.

Before long everyone should be writing browser animations this way.

Comment: Man this is a good answer.  You saved me time my next step wast to refactor to requestanimationframe

Comment: Yay!   For some reason, ` window.requestAnimationFrame(),` gives me mild brain-strain though it shouldn't because it's just a subtle variant of `window.setTimeout()`.

Comment: I'm gonna be mobile only while I travel for the next few day. However, I have few questions for you if ya have time. 1. Could we refactor the toscroll_ out of scope.totop so that I can call it from another function. 2. Could you annotate the dfrd.reject block, as I don't really understand?  3. Where would I put cancelRequestAnimation? Last, (hard) 4. Have you checked out rxjs and observable? Is it possible to cancel the animation say on keypress if this was to be an observable rather than a promise? I'll make an ng2 plnkr for testing this observable

Comment: Lastly none of my above questions will stop me from marking this correct once I have time to test.  Just you seem knowledgable and these are my next tasks to research and implement

Comment: 1. Undoubtedly yes, though I'm not really an expert in Angular. As currently written, `scrollTo_()` relies on closure for some of its data so the refactoring would be a fairly major change. Probably best addressed as a separate SO question.

 2. Done

 3. Would need to be addressed as part of (1).

 4. As far as I can tell, this question is all about discrete events. FRP is a cool way to hande data streams but appears not to be relevant here.